# Allow domain to be accessed from local area network instead of IP address using Dnsmasq

Tags: server, dnsmasq

Web Server setup on Ubuntu 16.04 for www.abc.com, using Dynamic DNS provider. Domain www.abc.com is registered with registrar. Able to access domain from outside network perfectly good. Portforwarding all done.

But, in the local LAN, unable to access www.abc.com from browser. Local IP is 192.168.1.123 for the Ubuntu Web Server. Will link me to Router login page. Understand that i'm able to edit each client PCs hosts file, but this is not what we want, as quite a no. of domains and PCs to edit over time.

The other option is via Dnsmasq from what i read. I tried most of the suggestions in serverfault but still couldn't get it work. Can some experts advice what should be the right configuration?

3rd option is via Router DNSmasq but router do not have this feature or non-ddwrt supported.

```
$sudo nano /etc/dnsmasq.conf
domain-needed
bogus-priv
local=/abc.com/
address=/abc.com/192.168.1.123
listen-address=127.0.0.1
listen-address=192.168.1.123
bind-interfaces
expand-hosts
domain=abc.com
```

---

```
$sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
192.168.1.123   abc.com
```

---

```
$sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

*(Can't seem to save Google DNS here.)*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Can somebody help and advice?

Comment: What is you `DNS` server, If is router do you have possibilities to add some record? I guess that problem occur when you ask `DNS` server on witch ip is web server. `dns` server answer with public ip. Because of that you got router web interface.

Comment: I'm using Dynu.com for DNS and its the Public IP. I read that dnsmasq might be able to address this issue of viewing domain in local network. What to you think? Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not need dns server on local network if you can add record on router.

Comment: my router is not capable of adding such records.

Comment: Add `resolv-file=/etc/resolv.conf.dnsmasq` in `dnsmasq.conf`. After that create `nano /etc/resolv.conf.dnsmasq` and add in first line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in second line `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. `DNSMASQ` will use this file for resolving. First will look in `/etc/hosts` and if not find record then will go to `8.8.8.8`.

Comment: thanks for suggesting. I tried the steps that u provided and restarted dnsmasq service, but its still the same. What else can i try?

Comment: Witch DNS use `pc` from with you wish to access a local web. You must to use new dns server aka for dns you must put ip of local dns server.

Answer (score 0):

This is a NAT loopback / NAT hairpinning issue. I finally got this working by installing DD WRT on a router, enabling NAT loopback, and some basic config setup. There are some routers that support NAT loopback as well.